# Binding View::composer to match all views using wildcards?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have a navigation bar like this.

```
<li>Account</li>
   <ul>
      <li>Register</li>
      <li>Login/li>
      ...
```

I want to update this dynamically depending on `Auth::check()`. For example, if the user is logged in, "Account" will be changed with "My Profile Page" and child siblings will be replaced with an appropriate array.

I need to do this without editing `View::make calls` in my controllers. It looks pretty bad.

A solution like this is what I'm looking for;

```
View::composer('home.*', function($view) {
    if(Auth::check())
       return $view->nest('accountArea', 'home.navigation-loggedIn', null);
    else
       return $view->nest('accountArea', 'home.navigation-visitor', null);
});
```

If there are better alternatives, I would like to hear them too!

Comment: What about binding the view composer to your layout instead?

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that you're using layouts, and that you want to nest onto the layout (not your actual content's view).  So you'd do something like `View::composer('layouts.default', ...)`.

Comment: @PhillSparks Yes. I have a layout.blade.php which contains the general markup plus @yield('content'). So, doing `View::composer('home.layout', ...)` does automatically bind all the content files yielding on defined layout? Also I want to ask one more thing. (similar question) How do the people using Laravel handle 'always has to be binded' things like `'<title>{{ $title }}</title>'`. Is there any good-practice uses I can have a look at?

Comment: @Imaqtpie, [this may help you](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like the wildcards in Laravel works. They're just undocumented as of now.

```
View::composer('admin.layouts.*', function($view)
{
     if (Sentry::check()) $view->with('navigation', View::make('admin._partials.navigation'));
     else                 $view->with('navigation', null);
});
```

That's what I was looking for.

**Update: Here is an alternative solution**

You can also bind it to the layout, so all the subviews that extend that layout will benefit from composer.

```
View::composer('admin.layouts.main_layout', function($view)
{
     if (Sentry::check()) $view->with('navigation', View::make('admin._partials.navigation'));
     else                 $view->with('navigation', null);
});
```

It will bind composers to every view that does `@extend('admin.layouts.main_layout')`.

Comment: The view composer thing didn't work in my case. I sent a variable to a layout. but it was only available in the layout and not in views that extended it. I userd `View::share(key, value)`

Comment: Is it possible to have it not apply to some views? So reverse the wildcard?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `View::share('variable', 'value')` to share a variable across all views.

Comment: Goes into routes.php I believe?

Comment: Depends, I like to create a `composers.php` file to put my View composers so I usually put them there.

Answer (score 0):

Like Aristona says (thanks for de advice!): wildcards are allowed. Glancing at the code, we can see how Composers are Event Listeners, and in that section of the documentation is pointed out: [Wildcard event listeners](http://laravel.com/docs/events#wildcard-listeners).

Adding a little bit more, ultimately, `Str::is()` is used by `Events\Dispatcher` to detect wildcar listeners. For example, something like this:

```
str_is('namespace::*.view', 'namespace::folder.view')
```

In short, I agree that would not hurt a small informative phrase :)