# Laravel: How to use composer to inject data across all views?

Tags: laravel

I want to offload some HTML sections of my site into partials (includes) files rather than repeating the information in each view or layout. However, I also need them to contain specific data. An obvious example is the head section; I would like to put this into a partial, however I also want to be able to set the document title and META fields for each page.

I think the best way is to use [Laravel's view-composer](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers)

As per the docs, I can use an array to define the composer for multiple views at once:

```
View::composer(array('view1','view2', 'view3'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

However, what if I want to use this composer for every view, as I do in this case?

There's a few answers kicking around SO (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711854/binding-viewcomposer-to-match-all-views-using-wildcards)) which suggests I use a wildcard. So here's my code:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('header', View::make('partials.head', $view->getData()));
    $view->with('footer', View::make('partials.footer', $view->getData()));
});
```

Here's the problem: Using this is currently giving me an *out of memory* error, which suggests that it is very inefficient (and therefore that I really shouldn't be doing this).

So do I really need to pass an array listing every page on my website?

Isn't there a way to use composer for every page rendered, like I can with `View::share();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is going to be unique for each view, there's no point in putting it in a view composer; you can do this just by using blade templates, and pass the page-specific data to the view from your controller.

Set up header and footer partials, then set up a base template that uses `@include` to load your header and footer partials, then a section for your content with `@yield('content')`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
@include('partials.header')

@yield('content')

@include('partials.footer')
...
```

Then your individual page's views would each extend this base template:

```
@extends('base')

@section('content')
//...specific page content here
@stop
```

In your header and footer partials, include `{{ $someData }}` for whatever specific needs to change from page to page, and pass that data to each view from the controller.

Comment: Thanks! A case of barking up the wrong tree I think... I just assumed that variables wouldn't be available in the child partials, and for some ridiculous reason I didn't even think to try it. Problem solved, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is now [possible in Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#basic-usage)

Put this is your `AppServiceProvider` `boot` method:

```
View::share('data', [1, 2, 3]);
```